# Trying to extract Latest Trading price of a stock using python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, stock

I am trying to extract the LTP of a stock using below code. It is not returning any value. Please tell the error in the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe")

input_keyword=input("enter the stock name/symbol/keyword:")

url="https://www.nseindia.com/search?q="+input_keyword

driver.get(url)

content=driver.page_source


soup=BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")

details=soup.find_all("div",class_="searchWrp")

print("Choose from the followings:")

for data in details:
    name=data.div.a.text.replace("\n","").replace(" ","")
    print(name)

driver.close()

stock_name=input("enter the stock name from above:")

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe")

url_stock="https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol="+stock_name

driver.get(url_stock)

content_stock=driver.page_source

soup_stock=BeautifulSoup(content_stock,"html.parser")

details_stock=soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"blkbox-whitetxt"})
for price in details_stock:
    LTP=price.find(span).text
    print(LTP)
```

### OUTPUT

---

runfile('C:/Users/hp/Desktop/sharemarket.py', wdir='C:/Users/hp/Desktop')

enter the stock name/symbol/keyword:axis bank
Choose from the followings:
AXISBANK
AUBANK
DHANBANK
HBANKETF
UTIBANKETF
CORPBANK
DCBBANK
HDFCBANK
ICICIBANKP
RELBANK
ClearingBanks
ListingofunitsissuedbyUTIAssetManagementCompanyLimited-UTIBankExchangeTradedFund(UTIBank
ListingCeremonyofUjjivanSmallFinanceBank
ListingofunitsissuedbyUTIAssetManagementCompanyLimited-UTIBankExchangeTradedFund(UTIBank
NiftyBankF&O
BankingSectorModule
ClearingBanks-InterestRateDerivatives
ClearingBanks-CommodityDerivatives
InvestmentBankingOperations-International
CommercialBankinginIndia:ABeginner'sModule

enter the stock name from above: AUBANK

---

Comment: driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe") why two of them.

Comment: price.find('span').text was off.

Comment: @arundeepchohan......i have used 2 chrome driver syntax because the first chrome driver was showing access denied when a particular stock is searched. So i have to use different chrome for searching a particular stock.

Comment: @arundeepchohan.....could not understand "price.find('span').text was off" solution.

Answer (score 0):

The last price (among other info) is loaded from external URL. You can use this example to get it:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=AXISBANK'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print('Last price:', data['priceInfo']['lastPrice'])
```

Prints:

```
Last price: 466.8
```

Comment: i want without json.